# Combine an arbitrary number of JSON files with jq

Tags: bash, jq

I can combine 2 json files using jq, thus:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1.json file2.json >merged.json
```

I can combine an arbitrary number of json files by using a loop and on the second and subsequent iterations, used the output of the previous operation as one of the inputs. And with process substitution, that can be done via a pipe:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1.json file2.json | \
   jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' <(cat) file3.json | \
   jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' <(cat) file4.json ...
```

But how can I script merging of an arbitrary number of files without writing intermediate versions?

(I imagine that with a VERY large number of files I will have issues with ulimits / file handles - I am not concerned about that yet).

Comment: You don't need process substitutions for that, `<(cat)` can be replaced with `-`.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that `*` potentially does more than you might think.
(See https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.7/#multiplication-division-modulo for details.)

The "+" operator on objects is much less complicated, so chances are that something like the following will meet your needs:

```
jq -n '[inputs] | add' file*.json
```

Comment: This method fails if one of `file*.json` is a stand-alone JSON array not in an object like `[0,1]`. The failure error is: `object ({"some key"...) and array ([0,1]) cannot be added`

Comment: @LéaGris - That’s why I mentioned “objects” explicitly. Also, the question pretty much implies that each file specifies a JSON object….

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single call to jq like this :

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i({};. * $i)' file{1..4}.json
```

Comment: Same issue here, as with peak's answer if one of the JSON files does not have an outer object container but is a stand-alone array.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really combine files like `.[0] * .[1]` but will merge an any number of files into a single object

```bash
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $s (.; .[input_filename] += $s)' *.json
```

Example output: combine `cars.json`, `cities.json`, `contacts.json`, and `countries.json`

```json
{
  "cars.json": [
    {
      "name": "AMC Ambassador Brougham",
      "brand": "AMC",
      "economy_mpg_": 13,
      "cylinders": 8,
      "displacement_cc_": 360,
      "power_hp_": 175,
      "weight_lb_": 3821,
      "0_60_mph_s_": 11,
      "year": 1973
    }
  ],
  "cities.json": [
    {
      "Continent": "Asia",
      "Country": "China",
      "City": "Shanghai",
      "Population": 24256800
    }
  ],
  "contacts.json": [
    {
      "person": {
        "personid": 123456,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "addresses": {
          "address": [
            {
              "addressid": "2",
              "street": "Street 2",
              "postcode": "1234 AB",
              "city": "City 1"
            },
            {
              "addressid": "2",
              "street": "Street 2",
              "postcode": "5678 CD",
              "city": "City 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "countries.json": [
    {
      "country": "Afghanistan",
      "Region": "ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)",
      "Population": 31056997,
      "Area_square_miles": 647500,
      "GDP_per_capita": 700
    }
  ]
}
```